# Multi-threaded queue for processing group products

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking, queue

I am honestly no idea on how to start coding this one. I am now studying things about threading and locking. But can you give me some insight on how to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this similar to `consumer producer` [problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) ?

You have customers placing orders and threads waiting to process them. Only difference is you have product categories which means orders are processed by several threads depending on the product type (ex : Product A , Product B).

Though it's hard to produce the code (which actually is your job), I will try to provide an guide you could try to adopt,

First you need to have separate `queues` for each product type. A queue preserve the `FIFO` requirement (Check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). And you need to have a separate dedicated thread for each `queue`. What this thread do is check whether relevant queue has products to process and process them if there are or if there isn't any product it can set to sleep/idle.

To make `queue` synchronized, you will need to use wither `locks` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx)). That means the producing method and handling thread need to access the shared resource, the `queue` without race conditions.

Furthermore you may start the processing thread when you have items in queue and dispose the thread when the queue become empty. But all the points I described above are still valid for that case.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I'm looking now for the things that you said.

Comment: You are welcome..  One more suggestion, try to build a prototype first, having dummy data and all sort of testing cases to verify the solution..